# Trying to figure out how to find the final distance on my turtle with random number

Tags: python, loops, python-turtle

This is my code, I'm trying to figure out how to get the total distance of the entire length that my turtle has traveled and I don't know how to figure it without taking it out of a loop which I can't do because the numsteps is an input. This is for school by the way

```
for a in range(numsteps):
    s = randint(-100,100)
    angle = random() * 2 * pi
    x = s * cos(angle)
    y = s * sin(angle)
    walking.goto(x,y)
distance = sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2)
finald.goto(x,y)
print("The final distance is {:,.0f}".format(distance))
print("Your total distance traveled is {}")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You have to save your *previous position* to compute the distance from the *current position* to it.

Then every time after computing the distance (near the end of the loop) the current position becomes a previous one:

```
from math import sin, cos, pi, sqrt
from random import random, randint

start_x, start_y = 0, 0                      # The starting point coordinates
previous_x, previous_y = start_x, start_y   

total_distance = 0                           # We will progressively increase it

numsteps = int(input("Number of steps: "))

for __ in range(numsteps):
    s = randint(-100, 100)
    angle = random() * 2 * pi
    x = s * cos(angle)
    y = s * sin(angle)
    # walking.goto(x, y)                     # I commented it out for testing
    distance = sqrt((x - previous_x) ** 2 + (y - previous_y) ** 2)
    total_distance += distance
    prev_x, prev_y = x, y
    
final_distance = sqrt((x - start_x) ** 2 + (y - start_y) ** 2)

print("The final distance is {:,.0f}".format(final_distance))
print("Your total distance traveled is {:,.0f}".format(total_distance))
```

Note the `__` instead of your `a` (or other regular name) — this special name (one or two underscore characters) indicates that its value is *out of our interest.*

(Because we use `range(numsteps)` only as a counter.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd make simplifications based on some observations:

1. Turtle already knows the distance function, no need to reinvent it
2. Moving *backwards* (negative distance) when we can head in any direction is redundant -- it's really no different than moving *forward* in any direction.
3. We can more easily calculate how far we *did* move than measure how far we *will* move.

This results in code more like:

```
from math import pi
from random import random
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

numsteps = int(input("Number of steps: "))

screen = Screen()

walking = Turtle()
walking.radians()

total_distance = 0  # sum of all distances traveled

for _ in range(numsteps):
    previous = walking.position()

    angle = random() * 2 * pi
    distance = random() * 100

    walking.setheading(angle)
    walking.forward(distance)

    total_distance += walking.distance(previous)

final_distance = walking.distance(0, 0)  # distance from where we started

print("Your final distance traveled is {:,.0f} pixels".format(final_distance))
print("Your total distance traveled is {:,.0f} pixels".format(total_distance))

screen.exitonclick()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
Number of steps: 100
Your final distance traveled is 356 pixels
Your total distance traveled is 4,630 pixels
>
```